# Поиск статуса по неуникальным имени клиента и адресу

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Необходимо вывести значения из столбца 3 на Листе 1.

[Таблица для примера](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UCwT0u1qnmEmbfd1hgviouExUYM8gfRRqtEiiA6zknc/edit?usp=sharing)

Не получается вывести текстовый результат с помощью формулы VLOOKUP. Вылетает ошибка: "Аргумент Параметр 3 в функции VLOOKUP поддерживает только значения типа "число"".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал обойти с помощью DGET(ошибка с возвратом нескольких значений), INDEX(MATCH, не получилось.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(ISBLANK($A$2:A);ISBLANK($B$2:B));"";VLOOKUP({$A$2:A&"|"&$B$2:B};{'Лист1'!$A$2:$A&"|"&'Лист1'!$B$2:$B};{'Лист1'!$C$2:$C};false)))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если кепку одевать на ноги - тоже ничего хорошего не получится :) Правильно, третий аргумент - это номер столбца (число!). Покажите пример таблицы, опишите задачу и покажите свое решение. И заголовок должен отражать проблему, а не мольбу о помощи

Comment: Таблица прикреплена сверху изначально.

Comment: Нам не видно формулу, которую вы ввели в вашу таблицу, поэтому напишите её здесь.

Comment: Таблица только для просмотра, редактировать нельзя (а как же проверять решение?), задача не описана... Что хотите получить?

Comment: Прошу прощения, изменил просмотр на редактирование

Comment: Зачем проверять и клиента, и адрес? Что-то из этого может повторяться? (например, тот же адрес у другого клиента или один клиент с разными адресами)

Comment: Именно так, и клиент может повторяться и адрес.

Comment: Уточнение: повторы возможны Клиент1-Адрес1, Клиент1-Адрес1, или Клиент1-Адрес1,  Клиент1-Адрес2?

Comment: Да, может быть сетевой клиент с одинаковым названием и с кучей разных адресов. Или в по одному адресу несколько разных клиентов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понимаю, что вас остановило от использования конкатенации? Возможно, я неправильно прочитал о проблеме, но вот это, вроде, работает

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(
  A:A&B:B;
  {
    'Лист1'!A:A&'Лист1'!B:B\
    'Лист1'!C:C
  };
  2;
))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вышел из ситуации таким образом 
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(({$A$2:A&""&$B$2:B}="");"";regexreplace(VLOOKUP({$A$2:A&""&$B$2:B};{'Лист1'!$A$2:$A&""&'Лист1'!$B$2:$C};2;false);$A$2:A;"")))

не идеально конечно, но работает...

Answer (score 0):

Сначала ищем номер подходящей строки, потом в столбце по номеру строки находим нужный статус.

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX('Лист1'!$C$2:$C;MAX(IF('Лист1'!$A$2:$A=A2;IF('Лист1'!$B$2:$B=B2;ROW('Лист1'!$B$2:$B)-1)))))
```

Два условия разнесены по двум `ЕСЛИ` для обрезания лишних вычислений

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы формула была только в верхней строке и протягивалась автоматически до последней, чтобы не загружать таблицу формулами в каждой ячейке (как в моей таблице).